# opencv Error opening File Could find no file with with path 'D://wade//frame%3d.jpg'

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I was just working on on my reading image sequence. One thing had really confused me a lot. I got this error that I don't know how to solve it. And all the other answer can't solve my problem.

> [image2 @ 0000015ee5876620] Could find no file with with path 'D://wade//frame%3d.jpg' and index in the range 0-4
>   warning: Error opening file (../../modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:537)

Anyone has same experience like me? How did you solve it? Thanks

btw, here is my code of reading sequentially images. Perhaps is code problem.

```
#include <iostream>   
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>   
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string first_file = "D://wade//frame%3d.jpg";
VideoCapture sequence(first_file);

Mat image;
namedWindow("Image sequence");

while (1){
    sequence >> image;
    if (image.empty()) break;
    imshow("Image sequence", image);
    waitKey(5);
}

cout << "End of Sequence" << endl;
waitKey();

return 0;
}
```

Appreciated the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing an invalid filename to the `VideoCapture` constructor.  `//` is not a valid path delimiter on Windows, use `\` instead (which is escaped as `\\` in string literals in C and C++).  But more importantly, `%3d` only works in C-style printf and scanf functions, which you are not using.

To do what you are attempting, you need something more like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

std::ostringstream filename;
filename << "frame" << std::setw(3) << std::setfill('0') << SomeNumberHere << ".jpg";

std::string first_file = "D:\\wade\\" + filename.str();
```

Or this:

```
#include <cstdio>

const char *fmt = "frame%3d.jpg";
int sz = std::snprintf(NULL, 0, fmt, SomeNumberHere);
std::string filename(sz, '\0');
std::snprintf(&filename[0], sz, fmt, SomeNumberHere);

std::string first_file = "D:\\wade\\" + filename;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
\\
```

instead of

```
//
```

Also try to change the name of the file.

Comment: JoshThunar but I have a series of picture. I still need to use %d, isn't it?

Comment: @JamieWu things like `%d` are only used with C-style printf functions, which your code is not using. In C++, to create a filename with a number in it, you can use a `std::ostringstream`, or `std::to_string()` if you have it.

Answer (score 1):

%3d starts looking for 001,002,003 and 004.
If you have frame100.jpg, it will not be found.

Comment: This is the only correct answer that takes into account opencv VideoCapture conventions.